# Using isotope, why doesn't my grid update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

This is my first time ever using isotope. So, I create the isotope instance inside of my document.ready function like so:

```
                        var grid = $('.headshots-list');

                    grid.isotope({
                        // options
                        itemSelector: '.headshots-list-item-alt',
                        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
                        sortBy: '[data-number]'
                    });
```

Then I set the values of each element in my grid layout including setting the data-number attribute.

```
 $("#headshot_" + $(this).val()).attr('data-number', 2); // Users who are not chairpersons

 $("#headshot_" + $(this).val()).attr('data-number', 1); // Users who are chairpersons
```

Then I try to sort the grid. Currently, I am using the setTimeout only because I was testing to see if maybe I had a race condition but it made no difference. The grid does not order itself in the way that I am expecting so that the user with data-number 1 will show before all other users. These attributes are being set. I have viewed the elements in dev tools to be sure.
As I mentioned earlier, this is the first time I have ever used isotope so not sure what I am doing wrong. Any pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

As requested below, this is the HTML where I build out the li that goes with this.

```
    <li id="headshot_<?php echo $user->ID; ?>"
                            data-number = "1" class="headshots-list-item-alt js-headshot <?php echo $user_terms_classes . ' ' . $board_status . ' ' . $number; ?>"
                            data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#memberInfo_<?php echo $member_id; ?>">
                            <div class="headshot-list-item-inner">
                                <div class="headshot-list-photo">
                                    <?php //suppress photo until they come in
                                    ?>
                                    <?php if ($photo_id): ?>
                                        <?php // echo wp_get_attachment_image( $photo_id, 'Avatar' ); ?>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <?php // echo '<img src="https:somedomain.com/imgs/user_img.jpg"/>'; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="no-margin">
                                    <a href="#"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
                                    <input type="hidden" class="user_id" value="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>">
                                    <span style="font-size:14px; display: block; position: relative; width: 100%;"
                                          class="chair_designation" id="chair_designation_<?php echo $user->ID ?>">
                                    </span>
                                </h4>
                                <p class="no-margin"><?php echo $title; ?></p>
                                <span class="headshot-list-item-tag">View Bio</span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

Comment: May you share the HTML to go along with it?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I just included it above.

Comment: Please may you remove the PHP from the example? (e.g. `<?php echo $user->ID; ?>`) Consider using a "stack snippet" so we can run the code.